# Testing Angular Web components(Custom Elements) with protractor

Tags: protractor, custom-element, angular11, angular12

When we use the angular custom element tag in the index.html and run our e2e tests using protractor, it causes timeout as angular is not found in the page as for Angular web components there are only entryComponents and no bootstrap component. Because building the angular application for deploying as a custom element doesn't need bootstrapping of component.

Answer (score 0):

To build our angular project for production with customElement and also test the same module in protractor with boostraping the component , below tweak in module bootstrap will work.

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    entryComponents: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
    constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

    ngDoBootstrap(appRef: ApplicationRef): void {
        if (environment.production) {
            const aboutSystemCustomElement = createCustomElement(AppComponent, { injector: this.injector });
            customElements.define('custom-app-component', AppComponent);
        } else {
            appRef.bootstrap(AppComponent);
        }
    }
}
```